# Cross checking key on Order received page

Tags: woocommerce

I was trying to integrate a custom payment gateway in Woocommerce. The order is completed and the payment gateway is working. But the people from the payment gateway give a high risk vulnerability of amount tampering. They are basically changing the key after the payment has been completed. They recommend to cross check the key and prevent woocommerce from generating the receipt after key has been changed.  [image]

Is there any way we can check that key .
Here is the code I am using :

```
  $order                  = new WC_Order($oid);
          if ( $ostatus == 'Success'){

                    $transauthorised        = true;
                    $this->msg['message']   = $this->success_message;
                    $this->msg['class']     = 'success';


                        $order->payment_complete($oid);
                        $order->add_order_note('HDFC payment successful<br/>Ref Number/Transaction ID: '.$bankref.'/'.$tid);
                        $order->add_order_note($this->msg['message']);
                        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

                 }
                 else{
                    $this->msg['class'] = 'error';
                    $this->msg['message'] = 'An error occured . '.$failmsg;
                    $order->add_order_note($this->msg['message']);
                    $order->update_status('failed');
                    //extra code can be added here such as sending an email to customer on transaction fail
                 }
             $redirect_url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
            $this->web_redirect( $redirect_url); exit;
```

Comment: were you able to solve this issue...I have the same problem from HDFC

Comment: yes i solved it. You need to store key in Session and cross check after transaction complete.

Comment: Do you have any code snippets...

Comment: Well I have a plugin for that.

Comment: Ok so would you share the plugin to me if you are OK to...I use ccavenue's plugin...It will be very helpful to me to finish this process....

Comment: Hi [Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5789786/rohit-kishore) Please share the plugin details, I am facing the same problem.